# How to tell if your edit to a question is rejected

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

Can someone tell me how to tell if my edit to a question is rejected?  It might be obvious, but I'm not sure.

When I made the edit the question had this text:

> This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I revisited the page a half hour later and don't see any evidence of the edit.  If this means the edit was denied, is there a way to find out why?  Is there any history log of what happened?

The user wrote:

> How Linux differs from other scripting languages?

It appeared clear to me that the user meant:

> How **Does Using** Linux differs from other scripting languages?

There were three or four other small edits in the body that also made the question clearer.

The user had made comments in the comment section that showed he was referencing scripting in the Linux environment.

So, being new (me) in editing questions to make them clearer to the community, I'm wondering is my edit had been rejected or is still pending.

The question:
[How Linux differs from other scripting languages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155971/how-linux-differs-from-other-scripting-languages)

Comment: It's in your profile: http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/81664/l-d-james?tab=activity&sort=suggestions (and it links to http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/61424 which explain why it was rejected)

Answer (score 2):

You don't get directly notified of a rejected edit, so you'll have to go through your profile to see it. From your profile, click on the **activity** tab, then filter it by **suggestions** (you can also use **all** if you feel like digging through everything). Find the entry that corresponds to the question you suggested the edit for, and then click the "**suggested edit**" link just before the link to the question:

[image: Image showing the location of the suggested edit link]